# How do i properly create a variable from a string in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables, concatenation

I wish to use the string 'activeVideo' as a variable but I cannot get it to work. I think I am pretty close to doing it right but ive been stuck for hours now… What am I doing wrong?

```js
firstVideo = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kxopViU98Xo?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0?ecver=2;autoplay=1';
secondVideo = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FWO5Ai_a80M?ecver=2;autoplay=1';
jQuery('.play-circle').click(function() {
  console.log(this.id + 'Video');
  activeVideo = this.id + 'Video';
  jQuery('.play-circle').fadeOut(0);
  jQuery('.video').fadeIn(0);
  jQuery('.video-close').fadeIn(0);
  jQuery('#' + this.id + 'Video').attr('src', activeVideo);
});
jQuery('.video-close').click(function() {
  console.log('closing video');
  jQuery(activeVideo).attr('src', '');
  jQuery('.video').fadeOut(0);
  jQuery('.video-close').fadeOut(0);
  jQuery('.play-circle').fadeIn(0);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.banner-wide {
  position: relative;
  height: 720px;
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/500') center/cover;
}

.banner-wide .text {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-left: 7%;
}

.banner-wide .text h3,
.banner-wide .text p {
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.video-thumbnail {
  z-index: 11;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 360px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.play-circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://addplaybuttontoimage.way4info.net/Images/Icons/13.png') no-repeat center/150px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.video {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 360px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.video-close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 14px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/8934-close-button1.png') no-repeat center center / 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-wide owc">
  <div class="video-thumbnail">
    <div id="first" class="play-circle"></div>
    <div class="video-close"></div>
    <iframe class="video" id="firstVideo" width="375" height="225" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="video-thumbnail">
    <div id="second" class="play-circle"></div>
    <div class="video-close"></div>
    <iframe class="video" id="secondVideo" width="375" height="225" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You simply dont. At least not *properly*

Comment: Please don't link to 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time. Just post your code right here in a code snippet.

Comment: Simply put `activeVideo = this.id + 'Video';` into the close function too and it should work. And note that you **need to declare variables!!** , for that use `const`,`let`,`var`. Then your code would crash in such a situation and you can get back onto the right track

Comment: The proper way is to create an array. I also fixed your other code: https://jsfiddle.net/Lta1mydu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings aren't executable and can't just be used in place of evaluated code.

However, object structures are nothing more than keys (that are strings) and values, so you can pass a string (via array indexing notation) into an object to extract the value of that key.

Since the string you are building corresponds to an `id` of an element, you can pass that string as a "key" to the `window` object and it will resolve the correct object because elements with `id`s become global properties.

Then, if you store the URLs to the videos in another object, you can pass the string to that object to extract the URL you need.

You also need to declare your variables and give them proper scope.

```js
$(function(){

  // By storing the data in an object with key/value pairs, the key names can be
  // accessed via the scope of the object later
  var obj = {
    firstVideo : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kxopViU98Xo?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0?ecver=2;autoplay=1',
    secondVideo : 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FWO5Ai_a80M?ecver=2;autoplay=1'
  }

  var activeVideo = ""; // Need to declare this in a scope that can be accessed from both functions

  jQuery('.play-circle').click(function(){

      activeVideo = this.id + 'Video';      
      jQuery('.play-circle').fadeOut(0);
   jQuery('.video').fadeIn(0);
   jQuery('.video-close').fadeIn(0);
      
      // Get the element stored in the global property and pass to jQuery, then
      // get the key out of the storage object and use as the source:
   jQuery(window[activeVideo]).attr('src', obj[activeVideo]);
      // Test:
   console.log(jQuery(window[activeVideo]).attr('src')); 
  });

  jQuery('.video-close').click(function(){
   console.log('closing video');
      // Elements with id's become global properties, so the string
      // of their id can be passed as a key to the window object:
   $(window[activeVideo]).attr('src','');
   jQuery('.video').fadeOut(0);
   jQuery('.video-close').fadeOut(0);
   jQuery('.play-circle').fadeIn(0);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
.banner-wide {
 position: relative;
 height: 720px;
 background: url('https://picsum.photos/1000/500') center/cover;
}
.banner-wide .text {
 width: 30%;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 margin-left: 7%;
}
.banner-wide .text h3,
.banner-wide .text p {
 text-align: left;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.video-thumbnail {
 z-index: 11;
 position: relative;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 50%;
 height: 360px;
 cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.play-circle {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  background: url('http://addplaybuttontoimage.way4info.net/Images/Icons/13.png') no-repeat center/150px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.video {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 360px;
 position: relative;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
}
.video-close {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 top: 14px;
 right: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: url('http://freevector.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/8934-close-button1.png') no-repeat center center / 20px rgba(255,255,255,1);
 border-radius: 100px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner-wide owc">
        <div class="video-thumbnail">
            <div id="first" class="play-circle"></div>
            <div class="video-close"></div>
            <iframe class="video" id="firstVideo" width="375" height="225" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
  <div class="video-thumbnail">
            <div id="second" class="play-circle"></div>
            <div class="video-close"></div>
            <iframe class="video" id="secondVideo" width="375" height="225" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. This one was spot on what i needed. Again, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Hmm ok. I just discovered that this solution doesn't work on iOS. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: @alc What message(s) do you see in the developer's console. I can't think of anything that is non-standard in this code.

Comment: as always, there's more than one way to skin a cat. this is a good answer too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two separate variables, you can define an object like:

```
var vids = {first: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/kxopViU98Xo?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0?ecver=2;autoplay=1',
           second: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/FWO5Ai_a80M?ecver=2;autoplay=1'};
```

And then use the object with the id as the key to index into it:

```
jQuery('.play-circle').click(function(){          
    jQuery('.play-circle').fadeOut(0);
    jQuery('.video').fadeIn(0);
    jQuery('.video-close').fadeIn(0);
    jQuery('#' + this.id + 'Video').attr('src',vids[this.id]);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

This will fix it...

```
jQuery('#' + this.id + 'Video').attr('src',eval(activeVideo));
```

DISCLAIMER: As you'll see from the comments below, it's not popular. I'm aware of that. You can stop down voting this. If you're among those who believe `eval()` is evil, feel free to not use this. But it's a viable solution, quickly and easily addresses the problem, and to not use it (IMHO) would be a premature optimization. Certainly feel free to do your own research to decide whether or not to go this route.

Comment: This will answer the question but not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I don't agree with this answer, but that's incorrect. It's fine if used appropriately. An example I can think of off the top of my head is when building a templating engine.

Comment: I know `eval()` gets a bad rap for performance reasons, but in this case, it's the simplest solution and not using it is a premature optimization. Simply saying "is never a good fix to any problem" is dogmatic. It's a viable tool, use it.

Comment: @ChrisGeirman It's not just for performance reasons. It's for security and scope reasons and it's not needed to solve any problem.

Comment: @RobertBolton We can quote articles all day, but if you don't have to use `eval()` to solve a problem and it opens up all these issues, then why use it, ever?

Comment: @ScottMarcus ...because sometimes you just need to get the job done.

Comment: @RobertBolton Well, that's cheeky. `eval()` can get the job done, but with several deficiencies. The approach I propose gets the job done without them. So, which is better?